# ¿Cómo validar numero telefonico SQL server con Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Buen día compas,
La pregunta es como validar el update o insert de un campo en SQL Server, tengo este trigger <strike>pero no funciona, necesito validar que el numero de celular no tenga menos de 10 caracteres.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?</strike>

Ahora funciona, me entra la duda de que pueden agregar 10 caracteres Numericos o de texto, como evito que ingresen caracteres de texto?

```
ALTER
TRIGGER VALIDATE_CELNUMBER ON DIRECCIONES
FOR INSERT,
UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM INSERTED
   WHERE LEN(DIR_TELFMOVIL) <> 10
  )
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR (
     'Por favor Inserte un número de celular valido, ejemplo 310XXXXXXX ', 16, 1);
    PRINT 'NUMERO ERRADO NO CONTIENE 10 CARACTERES';
    ROLLBACK;
  END;
END
```

Estructura de la tabla

```
DIR_ID | DIR_NOMBRE   | DIR_TELEFONO | DIR_TELFMOVIL

1     | MARIA GARCIA |      5215465 |    3105557799
2     | PEDRO PABLO  |      4234465 |    3123334455
```

Comment: Para verificar que tenga menos de 10 caracteres podrías usar Len (DIR_TELFMOVIL)<10. Tampoco es necesario usar un Trigger, podes usar un Procedimiento Almacenado que reciba el numero y haga la verificación y dependiendo el resultado lo ingrese o no

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me dijeron que un trigger porque el error debe saltar en la aplicación a la hora de producirse, es decir si el usuario lo ingresa mal debe informarle que lo está ingresando mal. de Procedimientos almcenados la verdad ni idea.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada recuerda que el trigger no se dispara atómicamente registro por registro sino que puede dispararse por un lote de registros, por lo que conviene tenerlo preparado para esto o en su defecto impedir el UPDATE masivo. Para validar la longitud del número yo agregaría al trigger lo siguiente:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM INSERTED WHERE LEN(DIR_TELFMOVIL) > 10)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'LOS NÚMEROS DE CELULAR DEBEN SER DE 10 DÍGITOS',
                 10,
                 1
              )
END
```